# if email exists add option value to dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a dropdown wich I want to populate with one option only if the email exists in the db. I am hiding the option value and using AJAX to search if email exists.

```
$('#email-input').live('change', function() {
    //ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: "email_check.php",
        data: {
            'email' : $('#email-input').val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.result) {
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            //error
        }
    });
});
```

Something is not working right.
Also, if can anyone help me to change the value of a string ($total) if email exists, to lose 100 to the value and display the final value.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I see you are using jQuery, why not use $('admDicCheck').hide() & $('admDicCheck').show() instead of document.getelement. Where and what is $total? I think you should revisit your question and ask what you need.

Comment: `$.live()` is deprecated and discouraged; use `$.on()` instead.

Comment: @immortal, $total is a total value gived by products in the cart.
Jared, I am new in this so I don't understand what to change. I looked on google for scripts and I tried to make them work on what I need. So please give solution complete.
Thx

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using?